# Получить массив из объекта

Tags: php

`var_dump($FORM)` выводит:

```
object(CFormOutput)#201 (30) 
{ ["__cache_path"]=>..... ["__error_msg"]=> string(0) "" 
["__form_validate_errors"]=> array(5)
{ ["ORGANISATION"]=> string(100) "Не заполнены следующие обязательные поля: Организация" 
["NAME"]=> string(86) "Не заполнены следующие обязательные поля: Ф.И.О"....}
```

Как можно получить массив `["__form_validate_errors"]`?

Comment: может `$FORM->__form_validate_errors`

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ из комментариев:

---

Попробуйте так:

```
$FORM->__form_validate_errors
```